# Ratio of two expontiated integrals containing logarithms

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, logarithms, exponential-function, improper-integrals

If

$$w(x) = -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) \ln f(x)  \hspace{1mm} dx$$

and

$$z(x) = -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x,y) \ln g(x,y)  \hspace{1mm} dx \hspace{1mm} dy$$

How can the following be simplified? and can it be expressed as a non-ratio equation?

$$\frac{e^{w(x)}}{e^{z(x)}}$$

Comment: Is there any reason to suspect that it *can* be expressed in such a way for arbitrary $f$ and $g$? It seems very unlikely to me.

Comment: so it is already simplified? i was more concerned about exponential and logarithmic rules surrounding ratios of such

Comment: I did not say it was "already simplified." I asked whether *you* have a reason to think that there *might* be a simplification. If you had a good reason, mentioning it might motivate people to try to help here, rather than (like me) dismissing it as a likely wild-goose-chase.

Comment: well for starters the functions $w(x)$ and $z(x)$ share a common form in that both are integrals containing logarithms, which is why the question is about any rules concerning a ratio whose numerator and denominator are both exponentials of integrals containing logarithms, given that the exponential and logarithmic functions are inverse functions of one another. the integral here, is a buffer between them so I don't know how they counteract in a ratio setting. if it makes things pliable, let's say $f(\cdot)$ and $g(\cdot)$ are distribution functions

Comment: $\frac{e^w}{e^z}=e^{w-z}$.

Comment: @Tobsn do you have a source or link that gives examples and proof of that rule?

Comment: That's school knowledge.